# Implement in-app purchase for existing iOS application

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an application that was made before in app purchase and we did two versions: free and paid. Now I want to move to one app with upgrade through app purchase.

I will implement the in-app purchase in the free version, so all next users that will upgrade, will use this feature.

What about old users that downloaded the paid version, how to get rid of the paid version without affecting existing users? Should I still update the paid version to have old users get the new features I added to my app?

Comment: Yes, that is probably the right thing to do